# Sorting of Dataframe's Columns Within List Based on a Reference Vector

Tags: r

I'm trying to sort a list filled with 5 different dataframes but with same column names, but just of different arrangements.

Reproducible Example:

```
d1 <- data.frame(y1 = c(1, 2, 3), y2 = c(4, 5, 6), y3 = c(5,6,7))
d2 <- data.frame(y2 = c(3, 2, 1), y3 = c(6, 5, 4), y1 = c(5,6,7))

my.list <- list(d1, d2)

> my.list
[[1]]
  y1 y2 y3
1  1  4  5
2  2  5  6
3  3  6  7

[[2]]
  y2 y3 y1
1  3  6  5
2  2  5  6
3  1  4  7
```

I'm trying to arrange each dataframe columns within the list into a specific order that I have already created under colnamesvec (see below.)

```
colnamesvec <- c("y3", "y2", "y1")
```

If I subset out each individual dataframe, I am able to achieve it using base R command. But is there a better way to loop through this easily to achieve what I want?

```
s <- my.list[[1]]
s[colnamesvec]
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `lapply` and reorder the columns for each dataframe.

```
my.list[] <- lapply(my.list, function(x) x[colnamesvec])


my.list
#[[1]]
#  y3 y2 y1
#1  5  4  1
#2  6  5  2
#3  7  6  3

#[[2]]
#  y3 y2 y1
#1  6  3  5
#2  5  2  6
#3  4  1  7
```

This is assuming that all the columns in `colnamesvec` is present in each dataframe in the list.

Comment: @RonakShah Sorry, noticed your post too late. There is some overlap with the linked post but it's not an exact duplicate; shall I re-open?

Comment: @MauritsEvers yes, imo it isn't an exact duplicate but I do have a feeling that there must be a post somewhere for this question, couldn't find though.

Comment: @RonakShah Ok, I've re-opened; if you find a more closely related post you can close it again. It does feel like one of those "asked-before" questions.